# Internal server error while executing insert query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

So, I have just started out with Laravel. I am trying to create a create task api, where I save the data to the database.

This is my routes.php

```
Route::any('/createTicket', 'ClientsController@store');
```

This is my controllers code(ClientsController):

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        echo "Abc";
        //exit();
        $input = $request->all('client_name', 'client_state');
        Clients::storeClientDetails($input);
        print_r($input);
    }
```

This is my Models code(Clients):

```
public static function storeClientDetails($data){

        echo "STOR";
        $id = DB::table('client_details')->insertGetId($data);
        print_r($data);
        print_r($id);
    }
```

I get the data from the store function. But, nothing is saved in database.

What is the exact issue here???

Comment: By nothing, you mean no new records in the database are created or the record is created but does not contain any of the data?

Comment: No new record in the database are created

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just doing `Clients::create($input)` ?

Comment: Yes, because the ID that would be returned from storeClientDetials, I will be using it to insert in another table.

Comment: `$client = Clients::create($input); echo $client->id;`

Comment: Still getting the same error. 500 Internal Server error

Comment: What error do you get?